# Entity Framework Core - recursive parent/child linking

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an "account" table that includes a string foreign-key ("parent_guid") to its "parent" account (if one exists).  I would like to create an entity that knows its parent, as well as all of its children.

Here is my entity:

```
[Table(name:"accounts")]
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("guid")]
    public string accountGuid { get; set; }
    
    [Column(name: "parent_guid")]
    public string parentGuid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("parentGuid")]
    public Account Parent { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Parent")]
    public ICollection<Account> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my dbContext:

```
public DbSet<Split> Splits { get; set; }
public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

public ReportContext(DbContextOptions<ReportContext> options)
    : base(options)
    { }
```

My query is through the 'splits' context as the source table, but I end up returning Accounts.  Maybe there's a better way?

When I query for an Account by Guid, I get a result, but 'Parent' and 'Children' are always null, even though 'parentGuid' contains the correct value, and I have confirmed that there should be child records.

Any idea how to make this work, either through annotations or fluent API?

Comment: Can you specifiy the relationship between `Splits` and `Accounts` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, EF Core requires explicit inclusion of relational entities.

```cs
var accounts = await dbContext.Accounts.Include(account => account.Parent)
                                       .Include(account => account.Children)
                                       .ToListAsync();
```

##EDIT

As per the edits to the question, this is one way to **Eager Load** relational entities, but I cannot speak to the efficiency of this query without knowing the relations and indexes.

```cs
public IQueryable<Split>
  FindAllByAccountGuidsPostedBefore(IEnumerable<string> accounts,
                                                       DateTime endDate) {
  using (reportContext) {
     return reportContext.Splits.Include(s => s.Account)
                                .ThenInclude(a => a.Parent)
                                .ThenInclude(a => a.Children)
                                .Where(s => accounts.Contains(s.Account.Guid)
                                 && s.Transaction.postDate < endDate);
     }
}
```

One way to obtain that information is by looking at the console when this query is run to find the SQL statement(s) this produces, or by asking someone who is more experienced in Relational Databases :)

Comment: That doesn't seem to have helped.  Here's my dbContext:

Comment: @James I don't see any code in the comment above, but I have used EFCore since it's inception and I can assure that this is the correct method to include relations. If you need to me to look at your code to see if there is another problem, please edit the question.

Comment: Sorry, had to step away and lost ability to edit.  Here's what I mean to write:

That doesn't seem to have helped.  Here's my dbContext:

    public DbSet<Split> Splits { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    public ReportContext(DbContextOptions<ReportContext> options)
        : base(options)
        { }

My query is through the 'splits' context as the source table, but I end up returning Accounts.  Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: No that's fine, can you post the query?

Comment: Here's the query method:

public IQueryable<Split> FindAllByAccountGuidsPostedBefore(IEnumerable<string> accounts, DateTime endDate)
        {
            using (reportContext)
            {
                return reportContext.Splits.Where(s => accounts.Contains(s.Account.Guid) && s.Transaction.postDate < endDate);
            }
        }

Comment: This works as written; I had a dumb error elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks and realised there's something called `thenInclude`, it helps!